# Accessing $display-breakpoints.xs-only in sass file with vue-cli3 project and vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

Looking for some direction on how to use $display-breakpoints.xxx in sass file.

I used vue-cli-3 to setup project and then added vuetify with a la carte option and am not sure whether one should import file into my style sheet or not. Also not sure which file to import if it is needed.
Error I get is *Expected Identifier* after *@media*

Documentation and various prior versions have me confused as to correct method.

I have confirmed that sass is compiling my files and that are being inserted as expected (accept for issue described)
What I have tried is

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
@import vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass
.test
  color: green
  @media $display-breakpoints.xs-only
    color: red!important
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for suggestions but I managed to get it working the way I want it to work.

Steps were based on [sass variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables)

In my case I added but didn't confirm I needed deepmerge and fibers - sass and sass-loader were already installed.

I did need to edit my vue-config.js file and add sass loader option after creating new file main.scss in sass folder.

```
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "~@/sass/main.scss"`
      }
    }
  },
```

I then imported the _variables.scss into this new main.scss file

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss';
```

and now in my Due stylesheet I can access the variables (which can be overridden in main.scss if required)

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.test
  color: green
  @media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'xs-only')}
    color: red!important
</style>
```

I wouldn't keep it as this structure and would use mixing to create easier to manage and read functionality but at least I can now access variables I wanted.

My issue I was trying to import directly into my Vue component's style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$vuetify.breakpoint` object in CSS directly.

I have two alternative solutions, try this.

**A. Define media queries for breakpoint into your mixin**

```
// e.g. assets/scss/mixin/vuetify-media.scss

$sm-breakpoint: 340px;
$md-breakpoint: 600px;
$lg-breakpoint: 960px;
$xl-breakpoint: 1264px;

// Extra small devices: on screens that are 599px wide or less
@mixin xs {
  @media only screen and (max-width: $sm-breakpoint - 1)
  {@content;}
}

// Small devices: when the width is between 600px and 959px
@mixin sm {
  @media screen and (min-width: $sm-breakpoint) and (max-width: $md-breakpoint - 1)
  {@content;}
}

@mixin lg-up {
...
}
...
```

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
@import "@styles/mixin/media.scss";

.test {
  color: red;
  @include lg {
    color: blue;
  }
}
</style>
```

**B. bind a HTML class into template**

```
<div :class="$vuetify.breakpoint.lg ? 'test-lg' : 'test'"></div>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.test-lg {
  color: red;
}
.test {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Apologies it's taken so long to reply.

Was wondering why you say you can use $vuetify.breakpoint in css seeing as I do have it working?